# Navigation with only Odometry

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, robot-pose-ekf, fake-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm trying to set up the navigation stack on a robot possessing only odometry sensors (wheel encoder, IMU published to `/odom /imu`). No camera/laser. The robot is also using `robot_state_publisher` to publish the transformations between robot coordinates.

I want to use only odometry sources (wheel encoder, IMU) to navigate the robot, so my plan is to use [robot_pose_ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf) to fuse the odometry data and use [fake_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/fake_localization) to localize the robot on the known map (since no laser is involved).

So I was wondering where I can change the default parameters in order to use `robot_pose_ekf` and `fake_localization` in my navigation system. Also, I could not find the launch file for `robot_pose_ekf` in the package directory (`/opt/ros/hydro/share/robot_pose_ekf`) as mentioned in the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf). There is no launch file for `fake_localization` in `/opt/ros/hydro/share/fake_localization` either.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192304/navigation-with-only-odometry/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-09**:
The fake_localization package only contains a node. You'll have to write your own launch file for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

robot_pose_ekf does not currently install the launch files. I've reported this as a bug: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/249

Until that is fixed, you can get the launch files from the [source repository](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/hydro-devel/robot_pose_ekf), or write your own based on the wiki page.

The fake_localization package only contains the fake_localization node; no launch files. It should be trivial to launch it from your own launch file.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-09**:
Thanks. For clarification, should I replace `fake_localization` node with `amcl_diff.launch` file in `move_base.launch`? and isn't `robot_pose_ekf` the default state estimator in the navigation package? If so, Do I still need to launch it manually?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-09**:
The move_base.launch described in the [robot setup tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) does not contain a robot_pose_ekf node.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-09**:
Since you're using fake_localization instead of AMCL, your launch file should launch a fake_localization node instead of including one of the AMCL launch files.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-09**:
Do you know what the default state estimator is in navigation stack?

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-09**:
and I'm getting the following error message when running the `robot_pose_ekf.launch` downloaded from the source repository:

```
 Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 32, column 70
```

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-09**:
The robot_pose_ekf launch file in the source repository is only 16 lines. I suggest you check to make sure you've downloaded it properly.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-09**:
You are right. It was my mistake. Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-09**:
and can you please tell me why I have to add `robot_pose_ekf` in `move_base.launch` when I'm using only odometry for navigation, but otherwise it does not need to be added. Does this means navigation stack by default is using some other package to fuse the odometry sensors?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-09**:
By default, the navigation stack does not do any sensor fusion. It is assumed that you have that setup elsewhere.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-09**:
Currently, I'm facing the problem addressed [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/163181/robot_pose_ekf-output-to-fake_localization/). Is there an easy way to make the output of `robot_pose_ekf` compatible with the input of `fake_localization`?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-09**:
Have you tried the robot_localization package as suggested?